# Cmake - Want to see intermediate .i files

Tags: c, cmake, c-preprocessor

I want to know how to make Cmake give me a target that will allow me to save the .i files from my **C** program with the macro expansion, etc completed.

Will I need to make a custom target to do this?

Comment: What compiler are you using? clang and gcc have `-save-temps` option

Comment: I am using gcc. I guess maybe what I am trying to figure out is how to make it so its optional, not "always on" for generating the preprocessor files.

Comment: `option(SAVE_TEMPS "Save temporary files" OFF)` `if(SAVE_TEMPS) set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -save-temps") endif` ?

Comment: I'll try something similar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your are using the Makefile generator, then there are already targets for .i files. Type `make help`, and you will see all the targets, including those suffixed by `.i`, `.s`, and `.o`.

Comment: Oh, that is nice. I didn't realize you got that by default. Is there a way to force cmake to generate them all by default at build time anyway, so I don't have to manually run make again for the individual files?

Comment: Not that I know, @Derek.

Comment: @Derek I've [added two different approaches](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38112086/85371) that automate stuff a little bit more

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to manually run the make targets and filter for .i extensions, you could do it like this:

```
for subdir in */
do 
    (cd $subdir && make $(make help |& grep \\.i$ | cut -c4-))
done
```

Alternatively, I sometimes used `compile_command.json` with `npm`'s command line tool for json:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON # ... 
json < compile_commands.json -ga "command" | sed 's/.cpp.o -c/.cpp.ii -E/' | sh -
```

Note however that there might be edge cases (like target directories that have not been created yet).