# What should I modify to only pre-process all C files in an entire project?

Tags: c, makefile, cmake, c-preprocessor

To solve various problems that I'm facing for a tool I'm developing, I'd like to be able to **generate pre-processed versions of all C files** ( `*.c` ) in a given project, especially to **remove macros** but also for some other details. I know that preprocessing can be done with either `gcc -E` or `cpp` for a single file, but when complicated dependencies and includes appear, as in huge projects, individual preprocessing is useless or completely unpractical.

Now, of course, those projects also normally will have specifications to compile the entire project also in an efficient way, such as a Makefile or a configure file. Thus, my question is: what exactly do I need to be modifying in there (or at least look for) to produce **only the pre-processed C files for each C file** in the project instead of making the project?

You can assume it's an open source project with C files, but (uninteresting) other files written in other programming languages could be there as well.

Comment: please remove c++ tag

Comment: As configuration and compiling works the same way for C++ files, I think it's pertinent.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cmake - Want to see intermediate .i files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21027266/cmake-want-to-see-intermediate-i-files)

Comment: I can see how you use [make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) to track dependencies and generate pro-processed files. Have you tried it?

Comment: I had a look at the answer you mentioned, @KenY-N, and tried the proposed solutions, although I get some errors. I do get some intermediate files so it seems to be the right approach. I'll keep you updated!

Comment: @RSahu can you be more precise? I have very little experience with Makefiles.

Comment: @KenY-N the solution there doesn't work for me as its recursion is not covering all files. In fact, for the big majority of the C files, I'm not getting the intermediate files.

Comment: Is the question about `Make` or `CMake`? If the former, why `cmake` tag?

Comment: @Tsyvarev, it's about both (or more precisely something involving both). Some of the projects I have use CMake, others use only Make and some other configuration files.

Comment: If you work with CMake, you should modify only `CMakeLists.txt` (and other CMake scripts), but **do not touch generated Makefiles**. If you work with plain Make, you should modify Makefiles. If you work with autotools, you should modify its files. These 3 types of projects uses **completely different** tuning, so it should be 3 *different answers* for resolve your problem. This is not how Stack Overflow works. Please, concentrate on a specific type of the projects, and edit the question accordingly. Currently, while you ask about both Make and CMake projects, it is **too broad**.

Comment: I disagree @Tsyvarev, since having completely different tuning is actually the source of my problem. I can't be asking one question for every project, that would be beyond the point of automating. So, someone who would have to face different projects could perfectly have found a way for some if not all three (simplified) cases you mention. Besides, even a partial answer is welcome, so only because you don't have an answer, it doesn't mean that nobody else does.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple `make` rule to generate pre-processed output files from `.cpp` files.

```
%.i: %.cpp
    g++ -E -o $@ $?
```

If you have `file.cpp`, you can generate `file.i` by using:

```
make file.i
```

You can setup a similar rule for generating `.i` files from `.c` files.

```
%.i: %.c
    gcc -E -o $@ $?
```

If the `.cpp` file or the `.c` file gets modified the `.i` files can be regenerated by running `make`.

Comment: This won't work as it doesn't take into account file inclusion, so it will just throw an error unless I specify the includes manually. That's why I'm asking this question in the first place.

Comment: @pedro: what do you mean by "specify the included manually"? Add `-I` options?

Comment: @rici Yes, exactly that. And that is something I cannot afford for this project.

Comment: @pedro: why not? `-I` identifies folders, not files, and unless you repeat filenames in different folders, which is almost always a bad idea, there's very little cost to supplying folders not needed for a particular compile. So you should be able to just make a list of places where headers might be and add it to CFLAGS so that it applies to every compile.

Comment: @rici because the files to be included depend on the projects, the projects have hundreds, if not thousands of files, and some of them include external libraries. Also, the point of this project is to automate a process, so it's out of question.