# How to see intermediate files created during C++ compilation process

Tags: c++, cmake, compilation, preprocessor-directive

When building an application in C++, I want to see all my intermediary files generated during the process like .o file, .i file, .asm file etc. But when I jump into explorer in windows, it shows nothing even after I try to show "hidden files".
I tried to read one [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21027266/cmake-want-to-see-intermediate-i-files) but it is involving some **CMake** thing.
Can these files be seen without using the CMake ? If yes How?

Comment: Temporary files are deleted at the end of the compilation process

Comment: You can see the assembly generated by the compiler for your code by typing it into https://godbolt.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the `-save-temps` compiler option. From the man page:

> ```
>  -save-temps
>       Store the usual "temporary" intermediate files permanently; name
>       them as auxiliary output files, as specified described under
>       -dumpbase and -dumpdir.
> ```

There are a bunch of other options to influence which files and what name they will get. But for learning purposes that is usually more than enough.